# Appium Android driver.presskeycode option not available for Maven Project

Tags: android, maven, appium

I am working on an Android App and have noticed `driver.presskeycode` command is not available in my Maven project.

I used the same code in standalone Java project and was able to execute the `driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode)`command.

**Maven dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>

        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Standalone Java project Jar files

Selenium Java 3.4.

Appium Java client 5.0.3

Appium version v1.6.5

Answer (score 0):

It's available but for the instance of `AndroidDriver` only. You need to cast your `driver` first:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidKeyCode;

private AppiumDriver driver;
...
AndroidDriver dr = (AndroidDriver) driver;
dr.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

If you run tests for Android it makes sense to create instance of `AndroidDriver` on appium session creation:

```
AndroidDriver driver = new AppiumDriver(url, capabilities)
```

Check [java-client tests](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/KeyCodeTest.java) for example

Comment: I am creating the instance of the Android driver. Reference below:

Comment: AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
  
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() throws MalformedURLException {
   
   DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
   cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android device");
      cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "C:\\Users\\Vipin.Malhotra\\Desktop\\Rogers\\src\\MyRogers_com.fivemobile.myaccount.apk");
      driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);  
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      
  }

Comment: Whats you project structure? from the code above it should work, anyway I attached link to official java-client examples.

Comment: Hi Dmle, the issue is calling this method in a Maven project. It appears to me an issue with the Appium dependency(I have tried using Appium Java client 5.0.3 as well as 5.0.0-BETA6) but this presskeycode method is not available.  However, I am able to use this method if I work on a standalone java project.  Did you try this on any of your Maven projects?

Comment: ```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.DEL));
```

Imports:

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally:

```
driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER))
```

Worked for me.

All the other options: `pressKeyCode`, `sendKeyEvent` did not work.

I'm using java-client 7.3.0